# Parked domains on Spamhaus DBL

Tags: domain-name-system, email, spam, nameserver

I've set up a nameserver to park a bunch of my domains (similiar to sedo, bodis etc). Everything is working well. Unfortunately, all my parked domains are instantly listed at spamhaus (DBL). No mail server is set up, and there isn't a single e-mail sent through my server. So it's really weird that my domains popup in the DBL. I must be missing something here.

Any thoughts regarding this matter are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This is reasonable. If a previously parked domain is used to send email, then either the one parking those has lost his nameserver credentials to an evil third party, or the company parking it is using the - possibly previously good - name to deploy more unwanted messages.

Keep in mind that the DBL lists not only looks at the actual domains, but also rates the nameserver, so if the nameserver IP is connected to a hosting company that allows spammers in their networks, then this affects the domains parked on there aswell.

If a domain is parked in any other way than being hosted empty with a respectable company, people shouldnt accept mails from there. Nothing surprising about that.

Comment: We thought about this is a well. The thing is, a domain name that I've hand registered yesterday, got listed immediately after pointing it to our name server. So even  'fresh' domains get listed in the DBL.